# Mustee 3060L shower pan

Tags: shower

I am installing a Mustee 3060L acrylic shower pan in my basement bathroom. This will be installed on concrete.

I am having a challenging time figuring out how exactly go go about installing this. The "manual" says use silicone between the pan flange and the studs to eliminate squeaking. It also suggests using a thinset mortar if the pan is not level. No marks or pre-drilled holes on flange.

Is the mortar necessary if the pan is completely level.

How should I go about fastening it to the studs, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

Thinset isn't necessary but works. Masonry mortar works just fine too but I'm a long time user of Structolite to set shower bases and yes it's necessary for a strong base. It gives you a solid feel to the pan. If you were on level plywood many do without but it doesn't have the same solid feel. I personally like to drill holes in the flange and use stainless screws to attach to at least two studs.

Comment: I am just curious if this goes against manufacturers recommendations. I did talk to a guy tonight that said some newer pans are designed to not fasten directly to studs. I have stood in this pan several times on the flat concrete and it seems about as solid as it would ever be. Not sure though.

Comment: If you mean the holes, I've drill 1/8 holes and use washer head screws.  Mustee calls for screws or nails w/ pre-drilled holes into studs. A mix underneath insures no movement after setting. Alternative to that is putting screws into the studs above the top of the flange.  Ceramic tile locks the unit in place. A mix underneath is important as the weight of the users rise. If you're heavy  the unit flexes when stepped on. Seen that happen and the rubber drain gasket has come loose. Solid feeling is better than a unit installed without one a mix. Follow instructions if finish is not tile.